# how to make the backgound transparent if image is half opaque?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

[image]

hi this is the image in question. some parts of it are fading off soft of. and im really new to photoshop. i have no idea how i can effectively remove the background of this logo. please help. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally for such simple shapes one would recreate this artwork in a vector application, such as Adobe Illustrator. It's not that complex. However if you *must* use Photoshop and must not redraw anything.....

- Open the **Channels Panel** if it isn't already open (Window > Channels)
- Drag the **Blue** channel to the `New Channel` icon at the bottom of the panel to copy it
  [image]
- Highlight the Blue Channel Copy and choose `Image > Adjustments > Levels`
- Move the left and right triangles inward to the edge of the histogram and click OK
  [image]
  This will darken the channel and increase it's overall contrast. So the solid areas become black
  [image]
- Hold down the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key and click the *thumbnail* for the Blue Channel Copy. 
  [image]
  This will create a selection (marching ants) based on the channel.
- Move the **Layers Panel** (with the selection active)
- Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click the `Add Mask` icon at the bottom of the **Layers Panel**

  [image]
  This will add a layer mask to the layer and make the white transparent
  [image]
  [image]

If you need to further refine things, you can use Levels or Curves on the **mask** you just created.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just in this case the actual shape is totally mixed partially to the white background. I guess this tries to be "an impossible geometry B" so it is a solid piece, it only has too bright highlight.

I tried to guess the intended shape and drew the missing piece of the edge. It's made with the pen and it has got a stroke:

[image]

After inserting the missing edge the shape (not the black edge) is selected with the quick selection tool and copied to a new layer:

[image]

After some practicing one can draw with the pen the whole clipping path, convert it to a selection and get substantially more accurate background removal result than with color and contrast based methods.